# Using PTY as a proxy for remote serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, pty

I'm working on an IO expansion device.

Among other things, it exposes a bunch of serial ports, which I want to expose on my Linux host as /dev/ttySomethingN

I could write a TTY kernel module for that, but I'd like to keep it on userspace for now.

The solution I've found is to use a PTY as a proxy: The master side talks to my device and the slave talks to my applications, and I use TIOCPKT_IOCTL to know when the device needs to reconfigure its speed/bits/parity/stop bits.

It works pretty well! [See my source](https://github.com/Expanduino/Expanduino-Python/blob/4407c7face5bbcd7c37e45a2321725ec67750fdf/expanduino/classes/serial.py#L60-L120)

But there is one little issue: [I cannot set the number of bits (CS5/CS6/CS7) or parity (PARENB) in a PTY:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1f55c718c290616889c04946864a13ef30f64929/drivers/tty/pty.c#L290-L291)

Any ideas why this restriction is in place? And how to work around it?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't

Comment: Thank you for the reply anyway.